I can't install an APK on the remote control of a DJI drone
I have a remote control for a DJI drone, and the operating system it uses is Android Lollipop 5.1.1. It turns out that it's very limited in terms of what I can do (basically, I can only use the DJI app to control the drone). My intention is to take advantage of the Android system to install an app that would be very useful to me. The problem is that I don't have Google Play, not even a file explorer. The closest thing I have is: Settings, Storage, Downloads. Even though it says that Downloads has 10MB used, when I enter that folder, it says "No Items" (the APK is copied there). I have already enabled developer options. Does anyone have any idea how else I could install an APK? Note: I don't have a web browser, Google Play, file explorer, email; I have almost nothing except the DJI app

If you have enabled Developer Options check it, if it contains the option for Android Debug Bridge (ADB). ADB access via USB from a connected PC would allow you access to adb install command and adb shell for file-system view and operations.

I don't know about DJI devices, but just a general note that manufacturers can customize their Android to lock it down and prevent any 3rd-party app installation, as has been seen on other brands like Kosher OS and Gabb phones.

DJI devices are locked down. It's designed to run as a controller only.

ok thanks to all
